# I want to make my table change its colors according to whether it is single or even

Tags: html, css

I have this code to make td's odds and evens background color For ROWS
so if someone got a new high score number a new td will be added
and be colored automatically

It's not working like you see in the screenshot. Wwhat's the solution?

[image]

```css
th {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}

tr {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f3f1f1
}
```

```html
<table id="scoreboard" CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA </td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>BBB </td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>CCC </td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: What's "not working" about it?  In the image, every even cell has a different background color...

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update it to show a [mcve]

Comment: Your posted CSS code works. You must have some CSS that breaks it.

Comment: the snippet added 3 tr's that i didn't write , i have linked it to a firebase so tr is being added automatically

Answer (score 0):

You are using the style on the `td` tag. That's why it's not working

Use it in `tr`

```
tr {
   background-color: #c4c4c4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the ROWS to change colour, then use the CSS on the rows

```css
th {
  height: 30px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  background-color: white;
}

tr {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f3f1f1
}
```

```html
<table id="scoreboard" CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=5>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Score</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 1</td>
    <td>Score 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Name 2</td>
    <td>Score 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work because tr is adding itself when a firebase update occurs i guess